# Print out local variables every time you step in gdb

Tags: variables, gdb, local

I am learning GDB and I was curious if there is a way to see the local variables every time that you make a step in your code. For example if I hit

`s`

I would like it really be

```
step info locals
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Type the command you want, it can be recalled using the <kbd>⬆️</kbd> and hit <kbd>↩️</kbd> to repeat the command. Using keyboard macros is also possible, see the [GDB Help](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_24.html).